# How to make an image resize to the screens height with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Unlike many people who want an image to fill out the whole screen, I only care about the image height. How can I use CSS (preferably not JavasScript) to make an image with any size, fill up to 100% of the maximum possible browser window **height** while keeping aspect ratio of the image, the re-sized width of the image in respect to the browser does not matter.

I'm working with this html:

```
<div class="images">
  <img/>
</div>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
img { height:100% }
```

or if you want to be explicit

```css
img { height:100%; width:auto; }
```

height 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/vz7q2bnk/
width 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/vz7q2bnk/1/

EDIT:

This answer needed some attention.  The demo was broken and generally a mess.  I've updated it with new images, updated rule to compensate for the inline nature of images, and normalized height and width of the body and html elements.

Comment: @Vickel Actually it looks like jsfiddle might be having server issues.  I'm getting a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 5):

This might be overkill:

```
.img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: no that's the right idea except you don't need the positioning, top, or bottom unless it's in a container.  The important part is leaving width auto

Comment: Yes as Joseph says the top or bottom is not really needed.

Comment: uh.. from what I've seen in this, what you really need to do is adress your container.  This method essentially removes the element from the container.  try making your images div `position:absolute;left:0;top:0;height:100%`.

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to take a look at the vh, vw, vmin and vmax CSS units – which are [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw). There's a good article describing how to achieve 100% height [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/7-css-units-you-might-not-know-about--cms-22573).

BTW – beware of whitespace: this can add an unwanted margin. Removing the space, adding a float, or using the `font-size: 0` hack will sort this out. Also, when using other methods, remember to set `height: 100%` for the body and html elements.